# PHP not getting xmlhttprequest post

Tags: php, jquery

I've been at this for hours and have yet to find a solution. Chrome's network activity shows that the post is being sent and the payload is "id=a1" but the php **always returns an empty string**. Either this is some silly typo that I've missed for the longest time, or my server host php.ini is blocking it. I contemplated the later, but I've used plenty of post scripts previously on this host without issue.

I've tried every combination I could think of with no avail :(

What could be causing this?

relevant .js:

```js
var xhr;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
  xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xhr.open("POST", "api.php", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www/form-urlencoded");
xhr.send("id=" + "a1");
xhr.onreadystatechange = display_data;

function display_data() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    alert(xhr.responseText);
  }

}
```

relevant .php:

```html
$id = $_POST['id'];
echo $id;
```

Comment: Make `xhr.send("id=" + "a1");` your last line of code and try again

Comment: This change gives me the same result :\

Comment: You made a typo in the request header string. You had `application/x-www/form-urlencoded`, you need `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Making this change alters the output from an error message mentioning an undefined index, 'id', to `a1`

Comment: Interesting, glad you found the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

Edited. Missed a semicolon.

```js
var xhr;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
  xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xhr.open("POST", "api.php", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send("id=" + "a1");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    alert(xhr.responseText);
  }

};
```

Comment: You don't need semi-colons after the end of a block. You've merely placed one after the closing brace for the handler for the `onreadystatechange` event. The error message remains the same as the one generated by the code in the question. ;) - The only reason your code now works, is that you've altered the request-header string in an edit.